# Orientation problems in captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:from connection:

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, avcapturesession

I am trying to process each frame of an AVCaptureSession and previewing the filtered image in an UIImageView. It works but the images in the UIImageView appear rotated (and distorted). I have been trying to find answers here and in Google but I could not find any working solution... Does anyone have any idea on what to try?

Btw, I am using Swift 3.0

This is the code I am using:

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    let attachments = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(kCFAllocatorMalloc, sampleBuffer!, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate)
    let coreImage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: pixelBuffer!, options: attachments as! [String : Any]?)
    var filteredImage = UIImage(ciImage: coreImage, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)

    if filter {
        NSLog("FILTER ACTIVATED")
        let filterType = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone")
        filterType?.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        filterType?.setValue(0.5, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)
        filteredImage = UIImage(ciImage: filterType!.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage!, scale: filteredImage.scale, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        self.imageViewPreview.image = filteredImage // UIImageView
    }
}
```

And this is what I see in the preview:

[UIImageView preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgqUx.jpg)

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Check you'r image orientation `UIImageOrientation.right` shouldn't it be  `UIImageOrientation.up` for the original orientation ...

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried it but the result is the same...

Answer (score 1):

I found it! It turned out I had to add the line `connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait` in that method...